# Where do I save my C code on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, codeblocks, evernote

I am a complete beginner as far as Programming is concerned. I used to practice coding on Codeblocks in Windows 10 and used to save the code on Evernote so that it can be accessed everywhere. Now I moved to Ubuntu (Dual Boot) and I use Eclipse here. Is there any place where I can save the code so that I can access it on my Windows OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using a hosted [Version Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

- [GitHub](https://github.com/)
- [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)
- [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/)

`Evernote` is for notes.

Answer (score 1):

If its just the matter of accessing it on your local windows machine, then save your codes on simple accessed folder and use [Linux reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) on your windows machine to access them, else use VCSs as suggested above